# Assembly referring resoruce dictionary is not getting loaded in prism

Tags: wpf, resourcedictionary, prism-4

I am using WPF prism for modular application development and each module that is present in the module catalog file is in different folder and they get added and removed from the region one at a time.Each module gets loaded from a its own folder and application exe is at different location. All the dependencies of the module is in its own folder.
In one module (dll) the view which gets added to region is having resource dictionary and with  Source of the ResourceDictionary as : 
    Source="/UIControls.Wpf.MessageBox;component/Themes/Generic.xaml"

If the resource DLL (UIControls.Wpf.MessageBox.dll) is present at the place where application exe is present then it works, that means view get added to the region. But this resource DLL has to be present at folder where module DLL is present(All the dependencies of the module is in its own folder). So if i remove this DLL from where application exe is then it gives FileNotFound exception and the module does not get loaded.
    How can I give source/path of the resource dictionary as codebase of the module? Source I don't want as application exe relative,I want the source as the path from where module is getting loaded i.e its codebase. Is there any way or other syntax so that source code is not the application exe relative. Please give me some solutions. One option I have got is to use AssemblyResolved event. But i dont want to use that.

Comment: What's wrong with the AssemblyResolved event?  It's the senior remedy for the situation you described.  How does your case differ?

Comment: that is the last option.Different teams make their own modules so I want to find solution that is good at the framework level. All the modules get hosted using this framework.